# Why does Calculate button remain gray in Group Stats Plugin for QGIS?

Tags: qgis

In my case I failed to use [Group Stats](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GroupStats/) plugin (2.0.30) with QGIS 2.14.11 and 2.18.3 on windows64.  Tested on several datasets: points, polygons, and csv.- But I am not sure what I have missed.

[image]

I want to click on this *Calculate* button.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the plugin when you have it configured.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You would need to specify on what value the **'min'** function should run.

For example : The following screenshot shows how to count number of countries of different types in each continent with an estimated population>1000 -
[image]

Also taking a look at this tutorial might be of help - [Group Stats tutorial](https://anitagraser.com/2013/02/02/group-stats-tutorial/)

Comment: Aaaaah! So it was the *NAME* in the Value section I had missed out. That did it. Many thanks!